# Communication between directive and service

Tags: angular

I'm trying to develop internationalization in my project without using 3-rd party modules and faced with the problem. Here is my translation service:

```
export class TranslationService {
    private translations: any;

    // load translations for the certain language
    loadTranslations(lang: string) { ... }

    // get translation by key
    get(key: string) {
        return this.translations[key];
    }

}
```

Here is my directive which will replace the text in the tag:

```
export class I18nDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() i18n: string;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef,
                private translationService: TranslationService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.el.nativeElement.textContent = this.translationService.get(this.i18n);
    }

}
```

Example: `<div i18n="global.welcome">This text will be replaced</div>`

**Problem:** currently, changing language will trigger TranslationService to load new translations, but directive doesn't know about that. What should I do to "ask" directive to use new translation and replaced the text with it?

Comment: Why not using ngx-translate instead ?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can create a Subject in TranslationService, and subscribe in the directive, some like

```
export class TranslationService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();
    public observable=this.subject.asObservable();

    loadTranslations(lang: string) { 
      ... 
   this.subject.next(true)
    }
   ...
}

export class I18nDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() i18n: string;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef,
                private translationService: TranslationService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.translationService.observable.pipe(
           startWith(null)
        ).subscribe(()=>{
           this.el.nativeElement.textContent = this.translationService.get(this.i18n);
        })
    }

}
```

Other option is create a method setValue in your directive

```
setValue()
    {
        this.el.nativeElement.textContent = this.translationService.get(this.i18n);
    }
```

And in your component get the Directive using ViewChildren

```
@ViewChildren(I18nDirective) labels: QueryList<I18nDirective>;
```

when change idioma

```
changeIdioma() {
    this.translationService.loadTranslations(this.idioma).subscribe(()=>{
      this.labels && this.labels.forEach(x => x.setValue());
    })
  }
```

You can see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egyzsw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (*)

(*) I put the two ways, just uncoment the lines

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I have already thought about your first way (with subject). I just want to know if there more concise and elegant way to do this. As for your second way, I don't think it's high scalable, because I need to put this change idioma in every component.

Comment: "playing" with decorators I add a new answer

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using a decorator, for reference two links

[Dependency injector using decorators](https://blog.bitsrc.io/dependency-injection-using-decorators-77dd4c89968e)

[Example of decorator for unsubscribe](https://netbasal.com/automagically-unsubscribe-in-angular-4487e9853a88)

Well, the decorator is some like

```
export function Translation(name:string) {
  return function(constructor) {
    const original = constructor.prototype.ngOnInit;
    const originalDestroy = constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy;
    const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([TranslationService]);
    constructor.prototype.ngOnInit = function() {
      this.translationService = injector.get(TranslationService);
      this.obs$ = this.translationService.observable.subscribe(() => {
        this[name] &&
          this[name].forEach(x => {
            x.el.nativeElement.textContent = this.translationService.get(
              x.i18n
            );
          });
      });
      original &&
        typeof original === "function" &&
        original.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function() {
      this.obs$.unsubscribe();
      originalDestroy &&
        typeof originalDestroy === "function" &&
        originalDestroy.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  };
}
```

So we only need in our component has the ViewChildren of labels

```
@ViewChildren(I18nDirective) labels: QueryList<I18nDirective>;
```

And decorate our component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
@Translation('labels') //<--this line before declare the class
                       //labels is the name of the variable of ViewChildren
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { ...}
```

You can see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yokmho?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftranslation.service.ts)